# How to send sms messages in Android using http requests using java code

Tags: java, android, api, http, sms

I want to send SMS using android application. For that I had refer following sites.

1. [ozekisms.com](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=583)
2. [Java Sms Example](https://dzone.com/articles/java-sms-example-%E2%80%93-how-send)
3. [How To Make HTTP POST Request To Server](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64)

And from following site I had registered and from using that API URL I had make that request.
http://websms.24x7sms.com/
http://www.24x7sms.com/downloads/24x7sms_http_api2.pdf

For that I used the following code.

```
protected void sendSMS(){

    Log.d("in","booking sms function");
    String nm1        = name.getText().toString();
    String ara1       = area.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String add1       = address.getText().toString();
    String mob1       = mobile.getText().toString();

    String message1   = "Name:"+ nm1 + "\n" + "Area:" + ara1 + "\n" + "Address:" + add1 + "\n"
            + "Mobile:" + mob1;



    BufferedReader reader = null;

    // Defined URL  where to send data
    String requesturl = "http://smsapi.24x7sms.com/api_2.0/SendSMS.aspx?APIKEY=********" +
            "MobileNo=+91**********&SenderID=SMSMsg&Message=You%20have%20new%20booking%20fro%20(variable%20please%20collect%20from%20them." +
            "ServiceName=TEMPLATE_BASED";

    try {

        URL url = new URL(requesturl);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        Log.d("after connection open",huc.getResponseMessage());

        Log.d("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", huc.getResponseMessage());


        }
```

After Running program I had get following message in logcat window.

```
11-06 20:14:57.830 6513-6513/com.******.*******.********* D/in: booking sms function
11-06 20:14:58.555 6513-6513/com.******.*******.********* D/after connection open: OK
11-06 20:14:58.556 6513-6513/com.******.*******.********* D/RESPONSE FROM SERVER: OK
```

But i never receive the message on particular mob number. Please Help me.

Thanks In ADVANCE....

Comment: Is there any particular problem while using  `Intent` ?

Comment: Did you try a `GET` request?

Comment: @samir_k hello sir, there no problem using Intent.

Comment: @KNeerajLal hello sir i also tried using GET but It's not working

Comment: Cross check if the gateway is working. See what you get as output for `huc.getResponseCode();`.

Comment: @KNeerajLal I also used this method but it can not display anything.

Comment: Didn't you get anything as reponseCode?

Comment: i didn't get any thing.